# Inkscape: svg dominant-baseline property not interpreted

Tags: svg, text, rotation, inkscape

Inkscape doesnt seem to interpret the svg dominant-baseline property.

I try to rotate a svg text in its center, both vertical and horizontal. In html (chrome) the following works well:

```
<html>
<body>
<svg width="1000" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<line x1="10" y1="10" x2="190" y2="190" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>
<line x1="10" y1="190" x2="190" y2="10" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>

<g transform="translate(100,100)"><g transform="rotate(0)">
    <text style="font-family:Roboto; font-size:100;" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">04</text></g></g>

<line x1="310" y1="10" x2="490" y2="190" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>
<line x1="310" y1="190" x2="490" y2="10" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>
<g transform="translate(400,100)"><g transform="rotate(90)">
    <text style="font-family:Roboto; font-size:100;" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">04</text></g></g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

which result in the following graphic:

[text rotation in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ3F6.png)

When i extract the svg tag element and put it in a stand alone svg file, Inkscape doesnt seem to interpret the

> dominant-baseline="central"

property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1000" width="1000">

<line x1="10" y1="10" x2="190" y2="190" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>
    <line x1="10" y1="190" x2="190" y2="10" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>

    <g transform="translate(100,100)"><g transform="rotate(0)">
        <text style="font-family:Roboto; font-size:100;" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">04</text></g></g>

    <line x1="310" y1="10" x2="490" y2="190" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>
    <line x1="310" y1="190" x2="490" y2="10" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:2"></line>

    <g transform="translate(400,100)"><g transform="rotate(90)">
        <text style="font-family:Roboto; font-size:100;" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">04</text></g></g>

</svg>
```

[text rotation in inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqaWx.png)

Any suggestion how to achieve the same result in inkscape highly appreciated.

Comment: If it doesn't work it doesn't work, what do you expect us to say here? https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/811862

Comment: sorry if this was not clear, the idea would have been to find out how to achieve the same result in inkscape ... i will edit my post.